# Lookbehind and lookahead PRCE

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

please, i have this example text:

> neco nechcem neco nechcem neco chcem y neco nechcem

and i want to capture text:

> "chcem"

(Is same as nechcem, but for this example i rename it)

My question is I have this regex:

```
(chcem)(?:(?<!neco).)*?y
```

Is there any other way to write it? Because, when I use this regex for large text I get catastrophic backtracking?

Comment: Try `(chcem)[^yn]*(?:n(?!eco)[^yn]*)*?y`

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. To me it looks like as simple as `chcem +y` right now.

Comment: Ok, i try to make better example with english
"stream url stream url stream url payed stream url" and i want to match url between "stream" and "payed"

Comment: If you're looking to match `chcem` as a full word, then you can simply use word boundaries: `\bchcem\b`

Comment: This `(?<=stream )url(?= payed)` fits your example.

Comment: @revo Thanks, but its not working, when between stream url and payed some other text(How i said i have a large texts), this is only small example, because, when i try my regex on large text, i get catastrophic backtracking.
I want to know if here is any other function which i can use :)

Comment: It depends on what you really want. It could be `(?<=stream )url(?:(?!payed).)*payed` or `(?<=stream )url(?:(?!stream).)*payed`. It doesn't result in a catastrophic backtracking either.

Comment: "(?<=stream ).*(url)(?:(?!stream ).)*payed" i need this, but when i use this on my data, i get error "catastrophic backtracking"

Comment: Are you doing this in Perl or in an application using libpcre? PCRE is not Perl regex, and in Perl the best solution can often be multiple regexes or other tools, so it might help to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The word "chcem" that you are trying to capture can be done with word boundary \b.
Check this Perl solution

```
$ export str="neco nechcem neco nechcem neco chcem y neco nechcem"

$ perl -e 'BEGIN { $x=$ENV{str}; while($x=~/(\bchcem\b)/g) { print "$1\n" } } '
chcem

$ export str="neco nechcem neco nechcem neco chcem y neco nechcem dasd chcem ab"

$ perl -e 'BEGIN { $x=$ENV{str}; while($x=~/(\bchcem\b)/g) { print "$1\n" } } '
chcem
chcem

$
```